# Reducing number of results in pager

Tags: search

[image]

As the image shows, the "Last >>" page button is not well adjusted, so i want to remove one item from this pager but can't figure out where can i find it to edit. I don't think it's configurable in apachsolr? Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Is that a View?

Comment: no its not, its just a search result page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using theme_pager in TEMPLATE.PHP (add it to your theme folder) . the code will be :

```
function theme_pager($variables) {
  if(arg(0) == "search" && arg(1) == "site") {
    $variables['quantity'] = 8; 
  }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome , I'm glad if I was of some help :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a **VIEW**, then change under Pager.
Click on **Paged, # items** then change **Number of pager links visible** as per your request.

Comment: It is a search page, not a view.

Comment: Use theme_search_page($results, $type) and check https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656
May be i am not right, but check this once.

Comment: Theming hole search_page is a bit hard , rather pager can be themed more easily